# Button onClick takes 2 clicks to trigger onClick function in desktop view but takes only 1 click in mobile view (expected)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, onclick

I have this list of text:

```js
const paperTopics = [
    "Teaching Aptitude",
    "Research Aptitude",
    "Comprehension",
    "Communication",
    "Mathematical Reasoning and Aptitude",
    "Logical Reasoning",
]
```

I'm trying to create a list of buttons from this, like:

```
{paperTopics.map((topic, index) => (
    <button
        key={topic}
        className={`border-1 w-full p-3 md:py-3 md:px-6 text-left gap-3 bg-slate-100 ${
            index === 0 ? "rounded-t-md" : ""
        } ${index === paperTopics.length - 1 ? "rounded-b-md" : ""} ${
        activePaperTopic === index ? "border-primary-500" : ""
        }`}
        onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log(index) // this is the problematic line
        }}>
            <p
                className={`text-sm ${
                    activePaperTopic === index ? "font-semibold" : "font-normal"
                }`}>
                    {topic}
            </p>
    </button>
))}
```

When I toggle mobile mode in dev tools, these buttons take only 1 click to trigger the onClick function. But in desktop mode, these buttons take 2 clicks in quick succession to trigger the onClick function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to solve. Are you able to reproduce in a sandbox?

Comment: No, I am myself unable to reproduce the issue again. I restarted the server several times. Initially it didn't work. But after restarting my machine, everything went back to normal suddenly.

Comment: Maybe some sort of temporary cache / hot reload issue. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
{paperTopics.map((topic, index) => (
<button
    key={index}
    className={`border-1 w-full p-3 md:py-3 md:px-6 text-left gap-3 bg-slate-100 ${
        index === 0 ? "rounded-t-md" : ""
    } ${index === paperTopics.length - 1 ? "rounded-b-md" : ""} ${
    activePaperTopic === index ? "border-primary-500" : ""
    }`}
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(topic)
    }}>
        <p
            className={`text-sm ${
                activePaperTopic === index ? "font-semibold" : "font-normal"
            }`}>
                {topic}
        </p>
</button>))}
```

Comment: What does this solve? What was the issue? Please don't just dump a load of code in your answer without any explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).